# Phrase request: one which is used to transition from generality to details

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

***Overall, 11% of Australians, or 1,837,000 people, were living in poverty in 1999. _______, aged people were the least likely to be poor, with poverty levels of 6% and 4% for single aged people and aged couples respectively.***

In the above sentences, I'd like to know a word/phrase to lead readers from the overall information to data on sub-groups that comes under the big one. Here, single aged people and aged couples are two sub-groups of Australians. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "In particular" would work well.

Comment: I might use "Specifically, ..." or something longer but with more meaning like "Looking at the population by age, ..."

Comment: You're talking about pretty  much the opposite of poverty in the second sentence.  Why not talk about which groups were the *most likely* to be poor and leave the exceptions to last?  As it is, it's something of a non-sequitur, and so there's no smooth transition.

Comment: It's just an example I gave. Let's say I changed it to 12% and 10%, what would you recommend?

Comment: It is not the percentage but the phrase "least likely to be poor". You're talking about those who tend *not* to be poor immediately after talking about poverty. You are  suddenly switching direction, as it were.  You'd need a statement to make that transition, not a simple "segue word".   Something like "But poverty does not affect all groups equally".

Comment: I wouldn't put any transition words here. You're simply listing facts. If you want to draw conclusions about them while you're stating them, fine, but that's not the job of "transition words".

Answer (score 1):

> Overall, 11% of Australians, or 1,837,000 people, were living in poverty in 1999. _______, aged people were the least likely to be poor, with poverty levels of 6% and 4% for single aged people and aged couples respectively.

Depending on the perception of the figure 11% and of the aged people, we have several groups.  I list down a few.

Group 1 considers 11% *low*, and can have *In particular* (from @Jetunsaure) and *Specifically*.

Group 2 views the aged people to be *normally poorer*, and can have *Unexpectedly* and *Surprisingly*.

Group 3 views the aged people to be *normally richer*, and can have *As expected*.

Group 4 is less specific about those perceptions mentioned above, and can have *Among them*.

*Among them* can be in Group 1 too.

**Edit**

*In particular* can be in Group 4 too for leading readers from the overall information to data on sub-groups.

Comment: I always thought "in particular" was neutral and fell into group 4.